# Django To Filter distinct content with counts

Tags: python, django

In Django I need to filter the data and display the result like. for example

```
Alabama(20)
Iowa(12)
```

Here "*Alabama,Iowa*" are State Names and inside the brackets "20,12" are no. of jobs available by the particular States.

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
     first_name= forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())
     last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())
     username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())
     email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput())
     password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
     companyname = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())

class jobs(models.Model):
     emp = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     referencecode = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     jobsummary = models.TextField()
     jobdetails = models.TextField()
     key_skills = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     states = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I tried to give views.py is like

```
def search_result(request):

     details = jobs.objects.annotate().order_by('state')
     return render_to_response('searchresult.html', {'details': details})

templates
<ul>
{% for d1 in details %}
<li>{{ d1.state }}({{ d1.count }})</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It displays only State name not a count. Give some clarification.

Comment: Add this to your annotate() `Count("id")`

Comment: Is not working remains the same

    Iowa()
    Alabama()
    Alabama()

Comment: I find your question confusing, could you please rephrase it, I don't see what you are trying to filter.

Comment: `annotate(count=Count("id"))` - should work

Comment: Iowa(1)
    Alabama(1)
    Alabama(1)
It display like this.

Comment: Oh, so sorry I assumed you wanted on "ids" try 'states'. :)

Comment: No changes in the output. Like this i given jobs.objects.annotate(count=Count("state")).order_by('count')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
jobs.objects.values('states').annotate(count=Count('states'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer its worked fine. Now I need to display User model Id or Jobs model emp_id

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be tricky, but u can do this by refer "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/"